# How to test "Streamlined Identity Flows" in simulator?

Tags: google-oauth, actions-on-google

We have created the endpoint for token exchange, but how do we test "[Streamlined Identity Flows](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow)" in Actions on Google simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the gala-demo tool to test these. Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#seamless_identity_verification

Comment: is it working for you?
What did you enter in the "GSI Client ID" field?